# PhoneGap FileTransfer Upload Not Found

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to upload an image taken with the device's camera via the FileTransfer.upload method and I'm consistently being given a `FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR`. I'm using Cordova 2.2.0 via PhoneGap Build.

I'm taking a picture and saving the URI for it into localStorage (via Backbone):

```coffeescript
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    (file_uri) =>
        params.file_uri = file_uri
        params.is_image = 1
        collection.create params
    (message) ->
        U.Alert "Failed: #{message}"
    options
)
```

Then attempting to upload that image:

```coffeescript
file_uri = @get('file_uri')

transferOpts = new FileUploadOptions
transferOpts.fileKey = 'attachment'
transferOpts.fileName = file_uri.substr file_uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1
transferOpts.chunkedMode = false

transfer = new FileTransfer
transfer.upload(file_uri, @url(), success, error, transferOpts)
```

With this, the FileTransfer's `error` callback is always thrown with the following:

```json
{
    code: 1,
    http_status: 411,
    source: "content://media/external/images/media/8416",
    target: "https://mywebapp.com/api/endpoint"
}
```

Code 1 is PhoneGap's `FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR` response code. But I've verified the file exists on the device. Firstly, I can display the `file_uri` as an image on the screen. Secondly, I can retrieve the contents of the image file via the Weinre debugger like so:

```js
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    console.log('Read as data URL');
    console.log(e.target.result);
};
reader.readAsDataUrl(file_uri);
```

The logged `data:image/jpeg;base64` response is the correct image.

Now, I even tried manually resolving the URI like so, as I've seen in one StackOverflow question:

```coffeescript
resolveLocalFileSystemURI file_uri, (fileEntry) => fileEntry.file (fileObj) =>
    transferOpts = new FileUploadOptions
    transferOpts.fileKey = 'attachment'
    transferOpts.fileName = fileObj.name
    transferOpts.chunkedMode = false

    transfer = new FileTransfer
    transfer.upload(fileObj.fullPath, @url(), success, error, transferOpts)
```

In this case `fileObj.fullPath` resolves to: `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.COMPANY.APPNAME/cache/1359412873161.jpg`

And *still* no luck. At this point I'm sure it's something stupid I'm missing!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and resolved by using source uri  in format "file://"

Comment: I have already the heading "file://" (automatically added) but I have the same error